# .htaccess if request url diffrent from some string than

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a trivial question about htaccess rewrite condition.
The think i want to do in my htaccess is:

When someone accesses my project from a url different from "example.com" to be   redirected to a specific controller, for example app_user.php

I need the syntacs for this condition redirect.

Thanks for your time

Comment: This is unclear: `accesses my project from a url different from "example.com"`  Accesses how? What is "my project"? This could be a referrer issue, or an issue with several server aliases pointing to the same server...

Comment: I got my answer, but i`ll make the question more clear just for future references. I have more than 1 domains pointing to my web project. I want all of the domains which aren`t "example.com" when accessing the project to be redirected to a specific front controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app_user.php
RewriteRule ^ /app_user.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry if i hadn`t explained it properly. I need when some accesses my project from a different url from : "example.com". The example that you gave fixes the problem if the path after the url is diferent.